# javafx gantt chart

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, gantt-chart

I would like to do Gantt chart in javafx, but there is no examples how can I do this. I tried convert bar chart to gantt chart, but this didn't bring good results. :/
Is there any easy way to do it?

Ps. sorry for my english ;p

Comment: Did you observe a source code of opened part of javafx 2?

Comment: I think, the only way to get it - is to create it by yourself, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as you don't comment on my comments, I'll leave a version of official answer.

Now, Gant diagram is not a part of JavaFX 2+, and I don't know about an existing samples, where it is already built. So, the answer is - to build it by yourself.

Some part of JavaFX is open source, javafx controls, and javafx-charts projects are open-sourced as well. They can be found here : http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/

You can observe code of bar charts, line charts (and, may be, a scroll pane - for large charts), and it should become clear enough to understand, how to build a Gant chart yourself. It will require some coding, yes..

Possibly, if it will be created well, you can even go through the process and contribute it into open jfx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try my commercial framework called FlexGanttFX for JavaFX Gantt charts.
http://www.flexganttfx.com